# Javascript modify array of objects and concat value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = [
  { id: '1', label: 'Last Name', value: 'Smith' },
  { id: '1', label: 'Last Name', value: 'Blogs' },
  { id: '2', label: 'First Name', value: 'John' },
  { id: '2', label: 'First Name', value: 'Joe' }
];
```

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
const output = [
  {key: 'Employee', value: 'John Smith'},
  {key: 'Employee', value: 'Joe Blogs'}
];
```

I was looking at using reduce, but am stuck on how to properly get a condition to say that if id is 2, then add to output.value, and if id is 1 then concat output.value to the value already there.

Both id 1 and id 2 are dynamic and can grow. Id 1 will always be last name and id 2 will always be first name.

Comment: What actually associates "John" with the last name of "Smith"? Is it because "Smith" is the _first_ Last Name listed and "John" is the _first_ First name listed that they are "linked"

Comment: why not `John Blogs`  !?

Comment: *"Id 1 will always be last name and id 2 will always be first name."* If you're not using the IDs to link related properties, how do you know which first name belongs to which last name?

Comment: @NickParsons
Position of the object in the array. So index 0 linked to index 2, index 1 linked to index 3, etc.

Comment: That's a pretty nasty approach. Then you first have to count the number of distinct IDs to figure out which values belong together.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yeah definitely nasty approach. 
It looks to be better for me to modify how the data array is presented to somehow get a better link with first/last name?

Comment: If you have control over the data format, why not just create objects with `firstName` and `lastName` properties?

Comment: Didn't think of it that way. But now you have given me something for a better approach. Cheers

Comment: There is issue with your data set. I can see two id 1 and two id 2. Both having firstname and lastname. So why can't the output be like ```John Blogs``` and ```Joe Smith``` ? Unless it's heavily hard coded. Which should not be the case.

Comment: @RakibUddin unfortunately that is how it is filtered. 
I.e i can get { id: '1', label: 'Last Name', value: 'Smith' } and modify it before it is put together by data set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `.reduce()` groups each `['value']` under `['label']['First Name']` or `['label']['Last Name']` which become arrays of `group` object.
- Next `.map()` iterates through `output['First Name']` and then current values of `output['First Name']` and `output['Last Name']` are concatenated and added to a new object created by `Object.assign()`

```js
const data = [
  { id: '1', label: 'Last Name', value: 'Smith' },
  { id: '1', label: 'Last Name', value: 'Blogs' },
  { id: '2', label: 'First Name', value: 'John' },
  { id: '2', label: 'First Name', value: 'Joe' }
];

function fullName(objArray) {
  let output = objArray.reduce((group, current) => {
    if (!group[current['label']]) {
      group[current['label']] = [];
    }
    group[current['label']].push(current.value);
    return group
  }, {});
  
  console.log(`.reduce() returns: (scroll down for final result)`);
  console.log(output);
  console.log(`fullName(data) returns:`);
  
  return output['First Name'].map((first, index) =>
    Object.assign({}, {
      key: 'Employee',
      value: first + ' ' + output['Last Name'][index]
    })
  );
}

console.log(fullName(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first group the related items. These days you can use the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object but normally most people would simply use an empty object (`{}`) partly because that's how it's always been done so other programmers can easily read your code and partly because the syntax is nicer to use.

So the basic idea would be this:

```
let group = {};

arrayData.forEach(item => {
    let id = item.id;

    if (!group[id]) {
        // if item does not exist in the group yet
        // then create item
        group[id] = {}
    }

    group[id][item.some_key] = item.some_value;
})
```

Then after grouping you can loop through the group and construct a new array:

```
let result = [];

for (let i in group) {
    result.push({
        some_key_you_want: i.xxx + i.yyy
    })
}
```

Now you have a `result` array containing the data you want. Of course we can write this in many different ways but the above is the general outline of the idea.

In your case we can do:

```
let group = {}

data.forEach(item => {
    let id = item.id;
    if (!group[id]) group[id] = {};
    group[id][item.label] = item.value;
})

const result = Object.values(group).map(item => {
    return {
        key: 'Employee',
        value: item['First Name'] + ' ' + item['Last Name'],
    }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first name and last names from the objects aren't related by ids and instead are [related by position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72525380/javascript-modify-array-of-objects-and-concat-value#comment128116311_72525380). Although this approach would work if OP changes their data.